# filter in Observable cannot applied to Function Boolean in Rxjava 2

Tags: filter, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

The filter in following code is trying to filter out odd numbers, but I cannot compile the code because it is complaining

Error:(114, 25) error: incompatible types: > cannot be converted to Predicate

It was fine when I was using rxjava 1 with Func1, how can I make it work with rxjava 2?

```
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        ints.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
    Observable.just(ints)
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> apply(List<Integer> ints) {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(ints);
                }
            })
            .filter(new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(Integer integer) {
                    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2222222 filter out odd numbers.........");
                    return integer.intValue() % 2 == 0;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> apply(Integer integer) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                    }
                    return multiplyInt(integer, 2);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2 onNext>>>" + integer.toString());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easy compiled with retrolambda or java8

```
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        ints.add(i);
    }

    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
    Observable.just(ints)
            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0)
            .flatMap(integer -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                }

                return multiplyInt(integer, 2);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(integer -> {}, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Or if you really want to have all this anonymous calsses your should change some signatures

```
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        ints.add(i);
    }

    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
    Observable.just(ints)
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(List<Integer> ints1) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(ints1);
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(Integer integer) {
                    Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2222222 filter out odd numbers.........");
                    return integer % 2 == 0;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                    }
                    return multiplyInt(integer, 2);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                }
            });
```

**Main issues in your code is Function instead of Predicate in filter as @JohnWowUs says.**
And Observable instead of ObservableSource in flatMap.

But I think retrolambda/java8 is much better with rxjava. Them allows write much less code and avoid issues like this using type inference.

Answer (score 4):

In rxjava2 I believe `filter` uses `Predicate` not `Function` e.g.

```
.filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Integer integer) {
                Log.d("RxFlapmapActivity", "flapMapEx2222222 filter out odd numbers.........");
                return integer.intValue() % 2 == 0;
            }
        })
```

Comment: Yup, was just going to answer this :)